# use a uniform buffer by Qt with OpenGL but it didn't work

Tags: qt, glsl, qtopengl, qopenglfunctions

I want to use uniform buffer for Matrices of model、view and projection in Qt.I chose QOpenGLExtraFunctions for calling glBindBufferRange function.But I found it no use.My floor.vert and object.vert shows 'model'、'projection' and 'view' were not declare in this scope and my program output was "QOpenGLFunctions created with non-current context". I thought the reason might be introduced by not calling glBindBuffer when I bind uniform buffer，but I found there is no glBindBuffer function in QOpenGLExtraFunctions. Although QOpenGlFunctions has glBindBuffer but there is no glBindBufferRange function in it.So how can I fix it?

**showcasewidget.cpp**

```
#include "showcasewidget.h"
#include "ui_showcasewidget.h"

Showcasewidget::Showcasewidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent), QOpenGLExtraFunctions(nullptr),
    ui(new Ui::Showcasewidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Showcasewidget::~Showcasewidget()
{
    objectVbo.release();
    objectVao.release();
    delete ui;
}

void Showcasewidget::make_object()
{
    objectVbo.create();
    objectVbo.bind();
    objectVbo.allocate(this->vertices.constData(), sizeof(GLfloat) * this->vertices.count());
    objectVao.create();
    objectVao.bind();
    objectShader->objectProgram.setAttributeBuffer(0, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);
    objectShader->objectProgram.enableAttributeArray(0);
}

void Showcasewidget::store_matrices()
{
    matricesVbo.create();
    matricesVbo.bind();
    matricesVbo.allocate(3*4*4*sizeof(GLfloat));
    glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, matricesVbo.bufferId(), 0, 3*4*4*sizeof(GLfloat));
}
void Showcasewidget::initializeGL()
{
    this->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    objectShader = new Shader(":/shaders/object.vert", ":/shaders/object.frag");
    floorShader = new Shader(":/shaders/floor.vert", ":/shaders/floor.frag");
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    camera = new Camera(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f));
}

void Showcasewidget::paintGL()
{
    QDateTime currentFrame = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    this->deltaTime = this->lastTime.msecsTo(currentFrame);
    this->lastTime = currentFrame;
    camera->processKeyInput(this->keys, this->deltaTime);

    QMatrix4x4 model;
    model.setToIdentity();
    QMatrix4x4 projection;
    projection.perspective(camera->zoom, (GLfloat)this->width()/(GLfloat)this->height(), 0.1f, 200.0f);
    QMatrix4x4 view;
    view = camera->getViewMatrix();
    store_matrices();
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &projection);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &view);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2 * 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &model);

    floorShader->use();
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 6);

    objectShader->use();
    make_object();
    objectVao.bind();
    for(int i = 0;i < this->vertices.count()/3;i += 3)
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, i, 3);
}

void Showcasewidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void Showcasewidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if(e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->lastx = e->x();
        this->lasty = e->y();
    }
    this->update();
}

void Showcasewidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if(e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        int cur_x = e->x();
        int cur_y = e->y();
        float xoffset = cur_x - this->lastx;
        float yoffset = this->lasty - cur_y;
        this->lastx = cur_x;
        this->lasty = cur_y;
        this->camera->processMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
    }
    this->update();
}
```

**showcasewidget.h**

```
#ifndef SHOWCASEWIDGET_H
#define SHOWCASEWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLExtraFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDateTime>
#include "shader.h"
#include "camera.h"

namespace Ui {
class Showcasewidget;
}

class Showcasewidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLExtraFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Showcasewidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Showcasewidget();

    QVector<GLfloat> vertices;

    QDateTime lastTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    GLfloat deltaTime;
    Camera *camera;
    int lastx, lasty;
    QList<int> keys;

    void make_object();
    void store_matrices();
    void initializeGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override;

private:
    QOpenGLBuffer objectVbo, matricesVbo;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject objectVao;
    Ui::Showcasewidget *ui;
    Shader *objectShader, *floorShader;
};

#endif // SHOWCASEWIDGET_H
```

**floor.vert**

```
#version 420 core

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 model;
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
};

vec3 gridPlane[6] = vec3[](
    vec3(1, 1, 0), vec3(-1, -1, 0), vec3(-1, 1, 0),
    vec3(-1, -1, 0), vec3(1, 1, 0), vec3(1, -1, 0)
);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(gridPlane[gl_VertexID], 1.0);
}
```

**floor.frag**

```
#version 420 core
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**object.vert**

```
#version 420 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 model;
};

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
}
```

**object.frag**

```
#version 420 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    if(gl_FragCoord.x < 300)
        FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else
        FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
}
```

I want to use uniform buffer in QT with OpenGL.